# Question about Artinian module

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question. Why every cyclic Artinian R-module M is Noetherian? I think M is isomorphic to R/I, for some submodule I. Then I don't know what to do next. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to use the fact that every Artinian ring is Noetherian. I'm assuming $R$ is a commutative ring. As you say, $M$ is isomorphic to the $R$-module $R/I$ for some ideal $I$. Since $R/I$ is Artinian as an $R$-module, it is also Artinian as an $R/I$ module. Thus the ring $R/I$ is Artinian, hence Noetherian, which means that $M \cong R/I$ is a Noetherian $R/I$-module, hence a Noetherian $R$-module.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: I have a follow up question.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189956/follow-up-question-for-question-about-artinian-module