# follow up question for question about Artinian module

Tags: abstract-algebra

There is a follow up question for my previous question [Question about Artinian module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189045/question-about-artinian-module). 
If we replace cyclic with finitely generated. Does the conclusion still hold? R is commutative with unit. M should be isomorphic to $R^k/I$, where k is the number of generators. I want to use induction, but I is not necessarily a submodule of $R^{k-1}$. So I guess my idea using "$R^k/I\simeq R^{k-1}/I\oplus R/I$"(I use"" since it is only an idea, not rigorous) does not work. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is again yes. See the answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61695/are-there-any-finitely-generated-artinian-modules-that-are-not-noetherian

Comment: Thanks! In this link, why we can say the composition series exist? Why the composition factors are all cyclic? If the composition series exist, then the module is automatically both artinian and noethrian.

Comment: If $M$ is generated by $m_1,\dots,m_k$, then you can take $M_i$ to be the submodule generated by $m_1,\dots,m_i$. Then $M_i/M_{i-1}$ is cyclic with the generator being the image of $m_i$. Note that it isn't guaranteed exactly to be a "composition series", in that the factors $M_i/M_{i-1}$ are not necessarily simple, only cyclic.

Comment: Oh, I see. It seems I have some misunderstanding about simple module. Thank you!